# C code do...while looping issue

Tags: c

I'm currently experiencing issues concerning a do...while loop in my C code. The problem is that when I enter an incorrect value to store in dataTest[51] it DOES validate and states the problem (e.g. packet length over 50, only numbers). However when it prompts me again to enter a valid value I type a correct value and press enter, but the enter isn't recognized as me "entering" that data into the variable, it is recognized as a newline acting as if there isn't a value there.

```
char dataTest[51];

do {

    int stp = 0;
    valid = 0;

    printf("\nPlease enter the packet data (maximum of 50 numbers): ");
    while(getchar()!='\n');

    scanf("%s", dataTest);

    length = strlen(dataTest);

    if(length <= 50) { 

        for(i=0;i<=length && stp!=1;i++) { 

            if ( (dataTest[i] >= 0 && dataTest[i] <= '9') 
              || (dataTest[i] == '0') ) {

                valid=1; //set the valid variable equal to 1

            } else {

                printf("\nData must contain only numbers, '%c' is not a number.
                       Please try again. \n", dataTest[i]);

               stp = 1;
               valid=0; //set the valid variable to equal 0

            }

        }

    } else {

        while(getchar()!='\n');
        printf("\nData should have no more than 50 numbers, you have entered
        %i",length);
        valid = 0;

}

} while(valid!=1);
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: In the first loop, the `getchar` call will cause the first character in the input to be discarded.

Comment: Also, where is the `while` part matching the `do`?

Comment: It would also be good to know how `dataTest` is declared.

Comment: The `while(getchar()!='\n');` will catch every key until (and including) the user presses Enter. And these will be ignored, since you're discarding the `getchar()` return values.

Comment: the one after the printf("\nPlease enter the packet data (maximum of 50 numbers): "); you mean?
also I apologize, i'll edit that in now

Comment: Ok @ericbn how exactly would I rectify the problem then?

Comment: If the user enter more than 50 character the check you have doesn't matter, you have a buffer overflow anyway. You might want to use [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead?

Comment: @Charlieabee, try removing both `while(getchar()!='\n');` lines.

Comment: @ericbn if I remove them both my program crashes and exits

Comment: If you type more than 50 chars (plus the new line char), the program will write to memory past the `dataTest` size, and that may crash it!

Comment: I see @JoachimPileborg. I've never used fgets before, how would I implement it in this program?

Comment: Just do `fgets(dataTest, sizeof(dataTest), stdin))`. Remember though that `fgets` leaves the newline in the buffer.

Comment: @ericbn but if I enter over 50 characters it gets validated. it's when I enter a VALID input (e.g. 1) on the second prompt that it crashes

Comment: `stp` is unitialized before is first used in the `for` loop. That may lead to undefined behavior. Enable all warnings in your C compiler (`-Wall`). Declare `int stp = 0;`

Comment: @ericbn, you're right, but unfortunately that hasn't fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The program works for me in your scenario IF I initialize the variable `stp` to 0. If think you can eliminate it altogether and use `valid` instead. This doesn't solve the buffer overflow for more than 50 characters, but I think this is not a concern for your scope of the problem.

**Edit:** the code that solves all the problems (... except the number of characters overflowed)

Here's the `fgets` solution as suggested by Joachim Pileborg  (notice `dataTest[i] >= '0'` and the elimination of the newline character):

```
int valid, length, i;
char dataTest[50+3]; // 3: '\n','\0' + one more to test 50 characters overflow

do {

valid = 1;

printf("\nPlease enter the packet data (maximum of 50 numbers): ");
fgets(dataTest, sizeof(dataTest), stdin);

length = strlen(dataTest);
--length;   //  remove last '\n'

if (length <= 50) {
    for(i=0;i<length && valid;i++) { 

        if ( (dataTest[i] >= '0' && dataTest[i] <= '9')) {

            valid=1; //set the valid variable equal to 1

        } else {

            printf("\nData must contain only numbers, '%c' is not a number.Please try again. \n", dataTest[i]);

           valid=0; //set the valid variable to equal 0

        }

    }
} else {
    printf("\nData should have no more than 50 numbers");
    valid = 0;
}

} while(valid!=1);
```

Comment: Enter, abac, Enter => "Data must contain only numbers, a is not a number.Please try again."
Enter, 123, Enter => do-while exit (OK)

Isn't this your scenario?

Comment: that section of the do...while works, if i enter 'g' for example it tells me to re-enter, and it allows me to do that. It's just the "50 characters " validation that doesn't work the second time around

Comment: You should remove the second `while(getchar()!='\n');` (the one in the `else` loop)

Comment: Liviu I've kind of fixed the problem. But I get a buffer overflow if I enter about 78 characters instead of the intended 50... an idea how to stop it?

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot solve the buffer overflow with `scanf`. It is really important ? I think `fgets(dataTest, sizeof(dataTest), stdin)` is ok, as Joachim Pileborg suggests, but this makes your validation to 50 characters useless. Do you want to also detect it?

Comment: Edited and added the code to detect that more than 50 characters were introduced. Also notice the `stp` elimination and the new use of `valid`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this sentence while(getchar()!='\n'); make you feel confused, you can get rid of it.

And the for loop should be

```
for(i=0;i<=length-1 && stp!=1;i++) { 
    if ( dataTest[i] >= '0' && dataTest[i] <= '9' ) {
        valid=1; 
    } else {
        printf("\nData must contain only numbers, '%c' is not a number.Please try again. \n", dataTest[i]);
        stp = 1;
        valid=0; 
    }
}
```